# Transform SHAP values from raw to native units with lightgbm Tweedie objective?

Tags: python, r, lightgbm, shap, tweedie

The utility of Shapley Additive Explanations (SHAP values) is to understand how each feature contributes to a model's prediction. For some objectives, such as regression with RMSE as an objective function, SHAP values are in the native units of the label values. For example, SHAP values could be expressed as USD if estimating housing costs. As you will see below, this is not the case for all objective functions. In particular, Tweedie regression objectives do not yield SHAP values in native units. This is a problem for interpretation, as we would want to know how housing costs are impacted by features in terms of +/- dollars.

Given this information, my question is: How do we transform the SHAP values of each individual feature into the data space of the target labels when explaining models with a Tweedie regression objective?

I'm not aware of any packages that currently implements such a transformation. [This remains unresolved in the package put out by the shap authors themselves.](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/pull/1041)

I illustrate the finer points of this question with the R implementation of lightgbm in the following:

```
library(tweedie)
library(lightgbm)

set.seed(123)

tweedie_variance_power <- 1.2

labels <- rtweedie(1000, mu = 1, phi = 1, power = tweedie_variance_power)
hist(labels)

feat1 <- labels + rnorm(1000) #good signal for label with some noise
feat2 <-rnorm(1000) #garbage feature 
feat3 <-rnorm(1000) #garbage feature 

features <- cbind(feat1, feat2, feat3)

dTrain <- lgb.Dataset(data = features,
                      label = labels)

params <- c(objective = 'tweedie',
            tweedie_variance_power = tweedie_variance_power)

mod <- lgb.train(data = dTrain,
                 params = params,
                 nrounds = 100)

#Predictions in the native units of the labels
predsNative <- predict(mod, features, rawscore = FALSE)
#Predictions in the raw format
predsRaw <- predict(mod, features, rawscore = TRUE)

#We do not expect these values to be equal
all.equal(predsTrans, predsRaw)
"Mean relative difference: 1.503072"

#We expect values to be equal if raw scores are exponentiated
all.equal(predsTrans, exp(predsRaw))
"TRUE" #... our expectations are correct

#SHAP values 
shapNative <- predict(mod, features, rawscore = FALSE, predcontrib = TRUE)
shapRaw <- predict(mod, features, rawscore = TRUE, predcontrib = TRUE )

#Are there differences between shap values when rawscore is TRUE or FALSE?
all.equal(shapNative, shapRaw)
"TRUE" #outputs are identical, that is surprising!

#So are the shap values in raw or native formats?
#To anwser this question we can sum them

#testing raw the raw case first
all.equal(rowSums(shapRaw), predsRaw)
"TRUE" 

#from this we can conclude that shap values are not in native units,
#regardless of whether rawscore is TRUE or FALSE

#Test native scores just to prove point
all.equal(rowSums(shapNative), predsNative)
"Mean relative difference: 1.636892" # reaffirms that shap values are not in native units

#However, we can perform this operation on the raw shap scores
#to get the prediction in the native value
all.equal(exp(rowSums(shapRaw)), predsNative)
'TRUE'

#reversing the operations does not yield the same result
all.equal(rowSums(exp(shapRaw)), predsNative)
"Mean relative difference: 0.7662481"

#The last line is relevant because it implies 
#The relationship between native predictions
#and exponentiated shap values is not linear

#So, given the point of SHAP is to understand how each 
#feature impacts the prediction in its native units
#the raw shap values are not as useful as they could be

#Thus, how how would we convert 
#each of these four raw shap value elements to native units,
#thus understanding their contributions to their predictions
#in currency of native units?
shapRaw[1,]
-0.15429227  0.04858757 -0.27715359 -0.48454457
```

**ORIGINAL POST AND EDIT**

My understanding of SHAP values is that they are in the native units of the labels/response when conducting regression, and that the sum of the SHAP values approximates the model's prediction.

I am trying to extract SHAP values in LightGBM package, with a Tweedie regression objective, but find that the SHAP values are not in the native units of the labels and that they do not sum to predicted values.

It appears that they must be exponentiated, is this correct?

Side note: I understand that the final column of the SHAP values matrix represents the base prediction, and must be added.

Reproducible example:

```
library(tweedie)
library(caret)
library(lightgbm)

set.seed(123)

tweedie_variance_power <- 1.2

labels <- rtweedie(1000, mu = 1, phi = 1, power = tweedie_variance_power)
hist(labels)

feat1 <- labels + rnorm(1000) #good signal for label with some noise
feat2 <-rnorm(1000) #garbage feature 
feat3 <-rnorm(1000) #garbage feature 

features <- cbind(feat1, feat2, feat3)

dTrain <- lgb.Dataset(data = features,
                      label = labels)

params <- c(objective = 'tweedie',
            tweedie_variance_power = tweedie_variance_power)

mod <- lgb.train(data = dTrain,
                 params = params,
                 nrounds = 100)

preds <- predict(mod, features)

plot(preds, labels,
     main = paste('RMSE =', 
                  RMSE(pred = preds, obs = labels)))

#shap values are summing to negative values?
shap_vals <- predict(mod, features, predcontrib = TRUE, rawscore = FALSE)
shaps_sum <- rowSums(shap_vals)
plot(shaps_sum, labels, 
     main = paste('RMSE =', 
                  RMSE(pred = shaps_sum, obs = labels)))

#maybe we need to exponentiate?
shap_vals_exp <- exp(shap_vals)
shap_vals_exp_sum <- rowSums(shap_vals_exp)
#still looks a little weird, overpredicting 
plot(shap_vals_exp_sum, labels,
     main = paste('RMSE =',
                  RMSE(pred = shap_vals_exp_sum, obs = labels)))
```

**EDIT**

The order of operations is to sum first and then exponentiate the SHAP values, which will give you the predictions in native unit. Though I still am unclear on how to transform the feature level values to the native response units.

```
shap_vals_sum_exp <- exp(shaps_sum)
plot(shap_vals_sum_exp, labels,
     main = paste('RMSE =',
                  RMSE(pred = shap_vals_sum_exp, obs = labels)))
```

Answer (score 6):

I will show how to reconcile shap values and model predictions in Python, both in raw scores and original units. Hopefully it will help you understand where you are in R.

**Step 1. Generate dataset**

```
# pip install tweedie
import tweedie
y = tweedie.tweedie(1.2,1,1).rvs(size=1000)
X = np.random.randn(1000,3)
```

**Step 2. Fit model**

```
from lightgbm.sklearn import LGBMRegressor
lgb = LGBMRegressor(objective = 'tweedie')
lgb.fit(X,y)
```

**Step 3. Understand what shap values are.**

Shap values for 0th data point

```
shap_values = lgb.predict(X, pred_contrib=True)
shap_values[0]
array([ 0.36841812, -0.15985678,  0.28910617, -0.27317984])
```

The first 3 are model contributions to baseline, i.e. shap values themselves:

```
shap_values[0,:3].sum()
0.4976675073764354
```

The 4th is baseline in raw scores:

```
shap_values[0,3]
-0.2731798364061747
```

Sum of them add up to model prediction in raw scores:

```
shap_values[0,:3].sum() + shap_values[0,3]
0.22448767097026068
```

Let's check against raw model predictions:

```
preds = lgb.predict(X, raw_score=True)
preds[0]
0.2244876709702609
```

**EDIT. Conversion between raw scores and original utits**

To convert between raw scores and original units for Tweedie (and for Poisson and for Gamma) distribution you need to be aware of 2 facts:

1. Original is `exp` of raw
2. `exp` of `sum` is `product` of `exps`

**Demo:**

1. 0th prediction in original units:

```py
lgb.predict([X[0,:]])
array([0.39394102])
```

2. Shap values for 0th row in raw score space:

```py
shap_values = lgb.predict(X, pred_contrib=True, raw_score=True)
shap_values[0]
array([-0.77194274, -0.08343294,  0.22740536, -0.30358374])
```

3. Conversion of shap values to original units (product of exponents):

```py
np.prod(np.exp(shap_values[0]))
0.3939410249402226
```

Looks similar to me again.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. While the method you provide describes how to extract the SHAP values for the units of the objective function (log-likelihood), those values are not in the the native units of the label. I've since learned that transformation back to native units is not straightforward, further discussion here: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/pull/1041

Comment: Can you clarify please what your problem is exactly? I thought you're having difficulty reconciling shap values with predictions. And I showed you how to do that in raw scores space. But you're not accepting answer. Why? Are you having difficulty with converting raw scores to original units? Also note, this is a regression. Log-likelihood is irrelevant.

Comment: The problem is that raw score space is not in the units of y (what I refer to as native) you describe in your answer. The goal is to extract SHAP values for each feature in the units of y you describe in step 1, such that they sum to the predicted value in the units of y.

Comment: @kdoherty Pls see **EDIT**

Comment: Yes, I understand that you first exponentiate the SHAP values and then multiply them to yield the prediction in the units of y. However, that is not my objective. Looking at you demo, my objective would be to convert each element of the array to the units of y. It is incorrect to exponentiate them, as is described by the SHAP authors in the GitHub link above. If you do so, you will find that the sum of the exponentiated values is not the prediction in the units of y.

Comment: Exponent of a sum never equals a sum of exponents...

Comment: Yes, and that is the core issue. How do we convert individual SHAP value elements to y?

Comment: I showed you 2 ways to do that: in raw scores and original. The figures are the same up to 15th digit after decimal point

Comment: Each element of the array in step 2 of the demo

Comment: I'm happy to routinely see familiar faces while trying to clarify what exactly is going on with SHAP across packages... ;)

Comment: @ desertnaut still reseasrching this great and highly underappreciated package by Steve Lundberg

Comment: ... what the heck? If I use the argument as `predict_contrib`, as advised in the [docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#predict_contrib), it will not work (no error either, it just returns the predictions)!!! But your `pred_contrib` works as expected! How did you figure that out? Anybody has opened an issue on this?

Comment: @desertnaut  It seems to me the difference is due to 2 lightgbm APIs: [Python](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#predict_contrib) and [sklearn](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html). I happened to look at class instance docsting so I arrived at the right place from the very beginning

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov not so sure - I'm using the Python API, not the sklearn, but `predict_contrib` gave me predictions, not shap values. Anyway, I'll have a closer look, and if it is so indeed, I'll open an issue.